# how can I drop just the defect record and process rest of the records in a batch

Tags: apex, batch

I have a batch which reads data from another system and update salesforce records the reference used is SFDC ID, which is one of the parameter from the response used to identify the right record in salesforce for update. 
Now the issue is suppose if I am processing 20 records in each batch and if the fifth record from the response has an issue say the ID did not match, then batch catches that exception and looks like that transaction is dropped at that point. Rest of the records will not get updated. Is there an option to drop only the defect record and process remaining records in a batch?

Pasting my code here I am an intermediate coder please suggest if I can optimise this code as well. Many thanks in advance :)

```
public class PamwinToSFDCUpdateBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts,Database.Stateful{
    //class variable declaration
    List<Cbd_plot__c> finalUpateList = new List<Cbd_plot__c>();
    String ErrorStr='';
    String SchemeNumber='';

    // Start Method
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){       
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select id,Pamwin_scheme_Id__c from Cbd_Site__c where Status__c='Inactive']);

    }

    // Execute Logic
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Cbd_Site__c>scope){
        List<Cbd_Site__c> siteList = (List<Cbd_Site__c>)scope;
        List<String> StrschemeIds = new List<String>();


        for(Cbd_Site__c site :siteList){
            StrschemeIds.add(site.Pamwin_scheme_Id__c);
        }
        Map<ID,Cbd_plot__c> AllPlotsMap = new Map<ID,Cbd_plot__c>([select Id from Cbd_plot__c where Site__r.Pamwin_scheme_Id__c IN:StrschemeIds]);
        try { 
            // Logic to be Executed batch wise 

            for(Cbd_Site__c site :siteList){
                system.debug('<<<<site Id>>>>'+Integer.valueof(site.Pamwin_scheme_Id__c.trim()));
                PamwinWebServices.BasicHttpBinding_IPamwinWCFService service = new PamwinWebServices.BasicHttpBinding_IPamwinWCFService();
                schemasDatacontractOrg200407Pamwin2.ArrayOfPamwinUnit UnitList = service.GetAllUnitsForScheme(Integer.valueof(site.Pamwin_scheme_Id__c.trim()));
                SchemeNumber = site.Pamwin_scheme_Id__c;

                for (schemasDatacontractOrg200407Pamwin2.PamwinUnit pamPlot : UnitList.PamwinUnit){

                    if(AllPlotsMap.containsKey(pamPlot.SalesForceID)){
                        Cbd_plot__c sPlot = new Cbd_plot__c(id=pamPlot.SalesForceID);
                        /*if(PamPlot.ApprovedHandover<>null){
                            sPlot.Actual_Handover__c = PamPlot.ApprovedHandover.date(); //Actual handover is salesforce only field
                        }*/
                        sPlot.Ledger_Code__c = PamPlot.LedgerCode;
                        sPlot.Pamwin_Scheme__c = PamPlot.SchemeDescription;
                        //sPlot.Tenure__c = PamPlot.TenureType; // These fields can't be edited in pamwin unless a new scheme is made, hence not needed 18/12/2018
                        //sPlot.Beds__c = PamPlot.Beds;
                        //sPlot.Persons__c = PamPlot.Persons;
                        //sPlot.Unit_Category__c = PamPlot.UnitCategory;
                        sPlot.Size_sqft__c= PamPlot.OutturnFloorAreaFT2;
                        sPlot.Size_sq_m__c =PamPlot.OutturnFloorAreaM2;
                        if(PamPlot.ForecastHandover<>null){
                            sPlot.Forecast_Handover__c = PamPlot.ForecastHandover.date();//realtime update on this field 
                        }
                        sPlot.Service_Charge__c= PamPlot.ServiceCost;
                        sPlot.name = PamPlot.Plot;
                        system.debug('<<<pamplot>>>'+PamPlot.Plot);
                        sPlot.Block_Ref__c = PamPlot.BlockReference;
                        sPlot.UPRN__c = PamPlot.UPRN;
                        sPlot.Flat_Number__c = PamPlot.FlatNumber;
                        sPlot.Flat_Suffix__c = PamPlot.FlatSuffix;
                        sPlot.Building_Name__c = PamPlot.BuildingName;
                        sPlot.building_Number__c=PamPlot.buildingNumber;
                        sPlot.Street__c = PamPlot.StreetName;
                        sPlot.Area__c = PamPlot.LocalAreaName;
                        sPlot.Town__c = PamPlot.Town;
                        sPlot.City__c = PamPlot.City;
                        sPlot.County__c = PamPlot.County;
                        sPlot.Postcode__c = PamPlot.PostCode;
                        sPlot.Current_Unit_Value__c = PamPlot.OutturnCompletionValue;
                        sPlot.Shared_ownership_rent__c = PamPlot.OutturnCompletionRent;
                        sPlot.Development_Cost__c = PamPlot.DevelopmentCost;
                        sPlot.Annual_Service_Charge__c = PamPlot.ServiceCharge;  
                        sPlot.Pamwin_Scheme_Status__c = PamPlot.SchemeStatus;

                        finalUpateList.add(sPlot);
                        system.debug('<<<final update list>>>'+finalUpateList);
                    }else{
                        ErrorStr= ErrorStr+'Plot missing in salesforce --> Unit ID -->  \''+pamPlot.SalesForceID+'\' Scheme Id:  \''+SchemeNumber+'\'\n';
                    }  

                }


            }  
            database.update(finalUpateList,false);

        } catch(exception ex) {

            if(ex.getMessage()=='Invalid id: '){
                ErrorStr= ErrorStr+'Salesforce Ids does not match with pamwin for this scheme --> Scheme Id:  \''+SchemeNumber+'\'\n';
            }else if(ex.getLineNumber()==32 && ex.getMessage()=='Attempt to de-reference a null object'){
                ErrorStr= ErrorStr+'Not able to fetch a valid scheme in pamwin --> Scheme Id:  \''+SchemeNumber+'\'\n';

            }else{
                ErrorStr= ErrorStr+'Effected Scheme -->  \''+SchemeNumber+'\'Line number -->  \''+ex.getLineNumber()+'\' Error Type -->\''+ex.getTypeName()+'\' Error message -->\''+ex.getMessage()+'\'\n';
            }
        } 
    }   

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        // Logic to be Executed at finish
        system.debug('<<<no of plots in update list >>>'+finalUpateList.size());
        if(ErrorStr<> ''){
            PamwinUtility.sendErroEmailOverNight(ErrorStr);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a code structure like this:

```
try { 
    // Do lots of complex work.
    Database.update(finalUpateList,false);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

The flow of control here when an exception is thrown during the `// Do lots of complex work phase` is that the remainder of your `try` block is skipped, and control moves directly into the `catch` block to have the error handled. When that happens, your `Database.update()` call is never reached.

To ensure fault-tolerant processing, you need to do two things here:

- Handle errors closer to where they occur. For example, if you're in a loop and you just want to skip a record if something bad happens, you can use an exception handler inside the loop:

  ```
  try {
      // Do stuff here.
  } catch (Exception e) {
      continue; // Skip to the next loop iteration.
  }
  ```
- Write code that doesn't throw errors it doesn't need to. There's no excuse for `catch`ing a `NullPointerException` in my book. You should write conditional logic to check for `null` values to prevent that from happening.
- As a corollary, validate your data. I don't know where your `Id` errors are coming from, but this strikes me as another area where a little debugging will guide you as to the conditional logic you need to write to avoid trying to utilize bad data, rather than just letting an exception be thrown.

Some languages are very exception-heavy and use them as a major flow control tool (Python is an example). Apex is a language where you'll want to use exceptions a little bit more carefully.

Comment: P.S. try-catch is not necessary when using allOrNone=false. No catchable exception will ever be thrown when allOrNone=false.

Comment: Right, but his code isn't throwing a DMLException in any case, to judge by his error-handling code.

Comment: Thank you David, your suggestions make a lot of sense to me. I will try to apply your points a update you.

Comment: Yes, Its not throwing any DML exception, if I simplify exception handling and do some defence coding should really help.

Comment: I restructured the code based on your suggestions. Batch works good now. Thank you David for your help.